How can I call delay task in Zappa Django?
In celery I can call task with <func_name>.delay().
How can I do it in Zappa?
I have task:
@task()
def task_name():
    pass


TL;DR;
They are meant to different purposes.
Celery is distributed task queue system. That's why you can delay tasks.
They are sent to a queue to be processed later.
On the other, hand Zappa enables you to deploy a serverless application on AWS Lambda.
If you want to send a request to Zappa, you can do this as a normal endpoint request, but this is not a queue system.
Introduction
From Celery Documentation:

Celery - Distributed Task Queue
Celery is a simple, flexible, and reliable distributed system to process vast amounts of messages, while providing operations with the tools required to maintain such a system.

From Zappa Documentation:

Zappa makes it super easy to build and deploy server-less, event-driven Python applications (including, but not limited to, WSGI web apps) on AWS Lambda + API Gateway. Think of it as "serverless" web hosting for your Python apps. That means infinite scaling, zero downtime, zero maintenance - and at a fraction of the cost of your current deployments!

Python Celery and Zappa serve different purposes in the context of web development and task management. Here’s a breakdown of their key differences:
1. Purpose and Use Case

Celery:

Celery is a distributed task queue system. It’s used to run asynchronous and background tasks (e.g., sending emails, processing images, etc.).
It enables the execution of long-running tasks in the background without blocking the main application.
Celery is often used with frameworks like Django or Flask to offload tasks to workers running separately from the main application.


Zappa:

Zappa is a framework that allows deploying Python WSGI applications (like Django and Flask) to AWS Lambda.
It transforms your Python web application into a serverless architecture by handling the deployment to AWS Lambda and API Gateway.
Zappa’s primary focus is enabling Python applications to scale without managing servers.



2. Architecture

Celery:

Follows a distributed architecture where multiple worker processes execute tasks from a queue.
Celery requires a message broker (like RabbitMQ, Redis) to hold tasks and communicate between the main app and worker nodes.
The architecture is focused on ensuring asynchronous task processing with retries and scheduling capabilities.


Zappa:

Zappa packages your Python web app and deploys it to AWS Lambda, a serverless compute service.
No persistent server is required; the app only runs when triggered by events like HTTP requests (via API Gateway).
Zappa abstracts away server management, auto-scaling, and load balancing by relying on AWS’s serverless infrastructure.



3. Task Handling

Celery:

Handles long-running and asynchronous tasks.
It allows tasks to be distributed across multiple workers and can schedule them for later execution.
Celery also provides mechanisms for task retries, monitoring, and result storage.


Zappa:

Primarily handles web requests and event-driven logic in a serverless manner.
Although AWS Lambda can handle long-running tasks, it’s limited by a maximum execution time (up to 15 minutes).
Zappa is not designed specifically for background task processing like Celery but can integrate with AWS services like Step Functions or SQS for task handling.



4. Scalability

Celery:

Scales by adding more worker nodes to process tasks in parallel.
Task queues can be spread across multiple servers, making it highly scalable for distributed systems.


Zappa:

Zappa relies on AWS Lambda’s automatic scaling capabilities, scaling with incoming requests or events.
No need to manage workers or servers; AWS manages scaling automatically based on demand.



5. Deployment and Hosting

Celery:

Celery workers need to be deployed and managed separately from the main web app.
Requires setting up and maintaining a message broker and backend for result storage.


Zappa:

Zappa handles deployment to AWS Lambda, making it easier to go serverless without worrying about infrastructure.
You don’t need to manage servers, workers, or brokers; AWS takes care of scaling, load balancing, and other infrastructure concerns.



6. Integration with AWS

Celery:

Celery is not tied to any specific cloud provider. It can run on various platforms as long as the required components (workers, message broker) are available.
You can configure Celery to use AWS SQS as a message broker, but it’s not natively integrated with AWS services.


Zappa:

Zappa is deeply integrated with AWS services, specifically AWS Lambda and API Gateway.
It simplifies deploying Python applications on AWS’s serverless infrastructure, leveraging native services like S3, DynamoDB, and CloudWatch.



7. Common Use Cases

Celery:

Offloading long-running tasks, such as sending emails or processing files.
Handling scheduled or periodic tasks (e.g., daily reports, cron jobs).
Distributed task processing across multiple servers.


Zappa:

Deploying Python web applications to AWS Lambda to run them without managing servers.
Building serverless APIs, microservices, and event-driven applications.
Scaling Python applications without needing to manage infrastructure.



Summary:

Celery is focused on managing and executing background tasks asynchronously, requiring a broker and workers to handle distributed tasks.
Zappa focuses on deploying Python web applications to AWS Lambda, enabling serverless architecture with automatic scaling and infrastructure management by AWS.

